# Hide Media Device from Network

Tags: windows, networking, media

On my network at work, my laptop shows up as a Media Device with my pc username next to it.  How do I hide this from them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume you're using Windows 7. Go to **Control Panel** > **Network and Sharing Center** > **Advanced sharing settings** and you can turn off **network discovery** all together or just turn off **Media streaming**.

Comment: Turning off Media Streaming will still show the computer as a media device.